# How to disable Ctrl+U using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event. The primary purpose of doing this is, preventing users from downloading any image or copying content from my website easily i.e. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for viewing my webpage's source code or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copying content directly from my webpage.

Currently, I am using this piece of code but it disables my entire keyboard

```
 <script>
    /*function check(e)
    {
    alert(e.keyCode);
    }*/
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 85 || e.keyCode === 117)) {//Alt+c, Alt+v will also be disabled sadly.
                alert('not allowed');
            }
            return false;
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: This is a pointless exercise. There is *nothing* you can do to prevent people from seeing your source code.

Comment: squeamish-ossifrage, thanks for a quick solution to my problem!!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Let me know if you find a way to disable my browser's *View Source* menu option and all of the developer tools (even with Javascript disabled). Then I'll give you half a dozen other ways of circumventing your efforts.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Wireshark, for instance? ;-)

Comment: Ctlr+Shift+I or browser menu Tools->Developer Tools show content of your page anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is finally what I got to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && 
            (e.keyCode === 67 || 
             e.keyCode === 86 || 
             e.keyCode === 85 || 
             e.keyCode === 117)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
};
$(document).keypress("u",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
  {
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: @KrishnaTorque, I have not tested it in a MAC machine yet, you can give it a try, I hope it should work.

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is the return statement.

Though I would suggest you use `addEventListener` and the like, this is a working copy of your code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && 
            (e.keyCode === 67 || 
             e.keyCode === 86 || 
             e.keyCode === 85 || 
             e.keyCode === 117)) {
            alert('not allowed');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
};
```

Comment: Page is still opening if we double time press ctrl + U

Comment: You can remove the alert function and just return false

Answer (score 3):

Its simple just use the following code it will disable only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> etc will works fine:

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && 
            (e.keyCode === 85 )) {
            return false;
        }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try check this link from jsfiddle.

[js](http://jsfiddle.net/dVSRM/)

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+U",function(){
     alert('Sorry\nNo CTRL+U is allowed. Be creative!')
    }),
```

it will simple show and error when you try to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on your keybord

But check the link, there is alot of code

Comment: No, don't just post your code in a JSFiddle, Pastebin or whatever: when those sites are down, your answer gets useless. BTW, that's a lot of code to prevent Ctrl-U and the like.

Comment: the reason why i added the code in JSfiddle is that there is so much code to make it work smouth.

Comment: Page is still opening if we double time press ctrl + U

Comment: @Rajat a lot has changed since then and the code did work back in 2013. Not sure how relevant your comment is giving the age of this question/answer

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Then you should delete the answer so that It can save a lot of time of other developers.

Comment: Rajat that would mean you should delete more than 60% of all questions on SO, and that would not be a good think. Event thought the thing changes it should always be left so other can see what have been tried.

Answer (score 1):

This will Disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and Right-click (make sure it's at the top of all your code) :

```
<!-- Disable CTRL U and Right Click -->
<script>
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 85) {
      return false;
    }
  };
</script>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;"></body>

<!-- disable CTRL U and Right Click -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable right click

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

To disable F12 options

```
document.onkeypress = function (event) {
event = (event || window.event);
if (event.keyCode == 123) {
return false;
}
}

document.onmousedown = function (event) {
event = (event || window.event);
if (event.keyCode == 123) {
return false;
}
}
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
event = (event || window.event);
if (event.keyCode == 123) {
return false;
}
}
```

To Disable ctrl+c, ctrl+u

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c" || pressedKey == "u")) {
alert('Sorry, This Functionality Has Been Disabled!');
//disable key press porcessing
return false;
}
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below script

```
<script>
/*function check(e)
{
alert(e.keyCode);
}*/
 document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 85 ||     e.keyCode === 117 || e.keycode === 17 || e.keycode === 85)) {//ctrl+u Alt+c, Alt+v will also be disabled sadly.
        alert('not allowed');
    }
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Page is still opening if we double time press ctrl + U

Answer (score -1):

Its simple just use the following code it will disable only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> etc will works fine: but it will disable your page source too.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> $(function () { $(this).bind("contextmenu", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }); }); </script>
   <script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey &&
            (e.keyCode === 85 )) {
            return false;
        }
};
</script>
```