# Disable the F12 keyboard button function in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to disable some buttons on all pages on my WordPress website (F12, Right-click and Ctrl-U) without using a plugin.

Comment: What do you want? Hide the code of your webpage? It is impossible to hide it completely. Once the code is sent, you have no longer control over it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Ctrl+U using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372394/how-to-disable-ctrlu-using-javascript)

Comment: This link is for one page only And it does not work for the whole WordPress template

Comment: Just don't do it, it'll result in bad user experience. You won't be able to hide your source code! Even if you disable `F12`, people could do `Ctrl + u` to view your source code!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved To do this, you need to add the following code to the function.php file.

```
    function wpb_hook_javascript() {
        ?>
<script>
          
//To disable F12 options
    
    document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
    return false;
    }
    }
    
    document.onmousedown = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
    return false;
    }
    }
    document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    event = (event || window.event);
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
    return false;
    }
    }

//To Disable ctrl+c, ctrl+u, ctrl+x
    
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    
if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c" || pressedKey == "u"||pressedKey == "x" ||pressedKey == "F12")) {
alert('Sorry, This Functionality Has Been Disabled!');

return false;
}
});
});

</script>
        <?php
    }
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

Answer (score -2):

You could create a new Hook Element.
See this article https://docs.generatepress.com/article/hooks-element-overview/

This example would disable right click and copy/paste:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" onkeydown="if ((arguments[0] || window.event).ctrlKey) return false"></body>
```

Comment: Is there a code that is for all pages of the template and is in the function?

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.